# How to Measure performance of an angularjs application by launching browser using Jmeter

Tags: angularjs, jmeter, protractor, performance-testing

I have measured real time page performance of an application using jmeter and selenium. Similarly, I also need to measure performance for angularJS applications by launching browser.

For functionality testing of the same angularJS application I have used Protractor, but for performance testing I couldn't able to find any tutorial related to launching browser using protractor using jmeter. can someone guide me through this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) approach for executing tests against the Angular application, you don't have to go for Protractor. [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) plugin provides easy JMeter integration with Selenium, you can install WebDriver Sampler using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

---

If you already have existing set of tests relying on Protractor you can kick them off via JMeter using i.e. [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) plugin which allows running any OS command or program in single or multi-threaded manner and measure the elapsed time.